# Could not connect to host PHP SOAP fault for ws security enabled webservice

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsse

I am trying to fetch data from SOAP webservice but its giving me could not connect to host i tried many solutions in my code as following:

```
require 'soap-wsse.php';

define('PRIVATE_KEY', 'technologyally.me.key.pem');
define('CERT_FILE', 'technologyally.me.crt');

class MySoap extends SoapClient
{

    private $_username;
    private $_password;
    private $_digest;

    public function addUserToken($username, $password, $digest = false)
    {
        $this->_username = $username;
        $this->_password = $password;
        $this->_digest = $digest;
    }

    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $saction, $version, $one_way =
        0)
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
        $doc->loadXML($request);

        $objWSSE = new WSSESoap($doc);

        /* Sign all headers to include signing the WS-Addressing headers */
        $objWSSE->signAllHeaders = true;

        $objWSSE->addTimestamp();
        $objWSSE->addUserToken($this->_username, $this->_password, $this->_digest);

        /* create new XMLSec Key using RSA SHA-1 and type is private key */
        $objKey = new XMLSecurityKey(XMLSecurityKey::RSA_SHA1, array('type' => 'private'));

        /* load the private key from file - last arg is bool if key in file (true) or is string (FALSE) */
        $objKey->loadKey(PRIVATE_KEY, true);

        /* Sign the message - also signs appropraite WS-Security items */
        $objWSSE->signSoapDoc($objKey);

        /* Add certificate (BinarySecurityToken) to the message and attach pointer to Signature */
        $token = $objWSSE->addBinaryToken(file_get_contents(CERT_FILE));
        $objWSSE->attachTokentoSig($token);

        $request = $objWSSE->saveXML();
        //print_r($request);
        //echo $location;
        //  $location='https://impl.hub.cms.gov/Imp1/ApplicantEligibilityService';
        return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $saction, $version);
    }
}
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);
$wsdl = 'WSDL/ApplicantEligibility.wsdl';
$context = stream_context_create(array('ssl' => array(
           "verify_peer"=>false,
                 //               ,"allow_self_signed"=>false,
        //'cafile'        => 'cacert.pem',
      //  'verify_depth'  => 5,
      //  'local_pk'=>PRIVATE_KEY,

     //   'allow_self_signed' => false,
        'ciphers' => 'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AES256-SHA:KRB5-DES-CBC3-MD5:KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-MD5:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA:RC2-CBC-MD5:KRB5-RC4-MD5:KRB5-RC4-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5:RC4-MD5:KRB5-DES-CBC-MD5:KRB5-DES-CBC-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA:DES-CBC-SHA:DES-CBC-MD5:EXP-KRB5-RC2-CBC-MD5:EXP-KRB5-DES-CBC-MD5:EXP-KRB5-RC2-CBC-SHA:EXP-KRB5-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5:EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5:EXP-KRB5-RC4-MD5:EXP-KRB5-RC4-SHA:EXP-RC4-MD5:EXP-RC4-MD5',
        )));
$sClient = new MySoap($wsdl, array(
   // 'location' => 'https://impl.hub.cms.gov/Imp1/ApplicantEligibilityService',
   // 'style' => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
    'trace' => 1,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
  //  'ssl_method' => SOAP_SSL_METHOD_TLS,
    'stream_context' => $context,
    "style" => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
            "use" => SOAP_LITERAL,

   'connection_timeout'=>60
    ));
//$sClient = new MySoap($wsdl, array('stream_context' => $context));
//echo file_get_contents('https://impl.hub.cms.gov/Imp1/HubConnectivityService');exit();
$sClient->__setLocation('https://impl.hub.cms.gov/Imp1/ApplicantEligibilityService');
$sClient->addUserToken('04.BKS.KS*.913.430', 'Qzk@4iTjUodAn2R', true);
//print_R($sClient->__getFunctions());
$parameter['PartnerWebSiteInformationExchangeSystem']['InformationExchangeSystemIdentification']['IdentificationID'] =
    '04.DSH.TS*.001.001';
$parameter['ExchangeInformationExchangeSystem']['InformationExchangeSystemStateCode'] =
    'GA';
$parameter['ExchangeInformationExchangeSystem']['InformationExchangeSystemIdentification']['IdentificationID'] =
    '04.DSH.TS*.001.001';

$parameter['PartnerAssignedConsumerIdentification']['IdentificationID'] =
    'ConsumerScenario';

$parameter['PartnerWebSiteUserCode'] = 'Consumer';
$parameter['ExchangeAssignedConsumerIdentification']['IdentificationID'] =
    '124838339';
$parameter['ExchangeUser']['ExchangeUserIdentification']['IdentificationID'] =
    'geoge.washington@yopmail.com';
$parameter['ExchangeUser']['RoleOfPersonReference'] = '';
//print_R($parameter);
try
{
    $out = $sClient->FetchApplicantEligibility($parameter);

    var_dump($out);
}
catch (SoapFault $fault)
{
    //echo $sClient->__getLastRequest();
    print_R($fault);
}
```

I got response from this on SOAPUI successfully which is using keystore and ws-security header , Somewhere I am doing something wrong can you point me in right direction , thanks in advance , I am stuck in this since forever :(

Comment: @Andez yes you will paid for that job , my previous question is deleted